# Ruby on Rails Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently building a registration system which will need to create both a user and an organization.  The Organization needs to have an Owner or System Admin.  I believe my second option is best as I can create the Organization, a Sys Admin Role and a User without any circular database issues.  My fear with the First option is that an Organization is owned by a user and that user also belongs to that organization.

First --

```
Class User
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :role
  has_one :organization_as_owner, class_name: "Organization", foreign_key: "owner_id"

Class Organization
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users
  has_many :roles

Class Role
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :users
```

Second --

```
Class User
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :role

Class Organization
  has_many :users
  has_many :roles

Class Role
  belongs_to: organization
  has_many :users
```

Using the Second option, I would utilize a permissions table for the Sys Admin, and permit them to add new Roles, etc.. Which setup would you prefer and why?  Would using a has_many through on either Option be beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably set up the relationships like this:

```
Class User
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :role

Class Organization
  has_many :users
  has_many :roles

Class Role
  has_many :users
  belongs_to: organization
```

This is assuming all users have only one role. This way, you can make the following calls:

`user.role`
`user.organization`

`organization.users`
`organization.roles` (this will just collectively list all the roles that the users inside the org have, can always run a uniq! on this if necessary

`role.user`
`role.organization`

However, I think you should also probably take a look at the excellent rolify gem that could probably help you do this out of the box: https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Comment: I see a problem with your example, I would need to create a separate role for each user.  The role(s) act as a group in the system, thereby allowing the Sys Admin, or Owner, to specify privileges for all users within a Role.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I see, so basically roles are specific to organization and the organization needs to control what specific priveleges are on each role right? In that case, user should belong_to role, and role has_many :users, edited.

Comment: which as I just read, is exactly how you had it... I suppose I would confirm that the second way is what you want, but also take a look at rolify !

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation to Rolify!  It looks great for another project I'm working on.  Thanks Again!

Comment: no prob, if this helped plz accept answer :) even if its just a confirmation of what you knew haha

Comment: I decided to go with Option2 but accepted your answer as you helped me confirm my path.